# Why does Spring continue to initialize the context even if a bean fails to instantiate?

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-bean

I found a strange spring behavior in instantiating the beans during initial context Loading. I had a bean that loads large ML models. Due to insufficient memory the bean failed to instantiate throwing Out java `OutOfMemoryError` java heap space exception. 
But this doesn't stop the application from instantiating, instead it continues to load the application.

Why does this happen? Is this expected?

checked the spring `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory` ,

```
try {
    // Mark this bean as currently in creation, even if just partially.
    beforeSingletonCreation(beanName);
    // Give BeanPostProcessors a chance to return a proxy instead of the target bean instance.
    instance = resolveBeforeInstantiation(beanName, mbd);
    if (instance == null) {
        bw = createBeanInstance(beanName, mbd, null);
        instance = bw.getWrappedInstance();
    }
}
finally {
    // Finished partial creation of this bean.
    afterSingletonCreation(beanName);
}
```

It digests the exception silently with comment `// Finished partial creation of this bean.`

Doesn't this affect the application stability? Why is it designed so?
Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that there is no catch statement here! Moreover, `OutOfMemoryError` is not an `Exception`, so it won't be caught by the standard general `catch (Exception e)`.

With this `finally` clause the `Throwable` is not caught. It must be caught (*digested*) somewhere else.

Why does Spring continue its work? It's based on a web server, not a standalone dedicated app, why should it stop working immediately? Not all exceptions are critical, even errors can sometimes (... rarely) recovered from. It is the programmer's duty to ensure all "his" throwables are properly handled, not Spring's.